# Is this an idiomatic use of reference class members?

Tags: c++

I have the following class definitions:

```
class Policy {
public:
    virtual DigraphNode getBestMove(DigraphNode &node) const = 0;
};

class NoPolicy : public Policy{
    virtual DigraphNode getBestMove(DigraphNode &node) const 
       {return DigraphNode();}
};

class Agent {
public:
    static NoPolicy noPolicy;
    Agent() : policy(noPolicy) {}
    void setPolicy(Policy &p) {policy = p;}
    Policy &getPolicy() {return policy;}
private:
    Policy &policy; // pointer so polymorphism should work
};
```

Agent::policy may store an object of any descendant class of Policy. To avoid using pointers, I made this member a reference. However, then I need to initialize it in the constructor, which forced me to define an artificial policy NoPolicy as you see in the code. This works, but seems to be a bit artificial.

To complete the picture, I ended up having the following usage in the client code:

```
Policy &policy = Agent::noPolicy;
switch(agentTypes[a]) {
case NON_COMPLIANT:
    policy = HeuristicBasedPolicy<MultiHeuristic>(nearExitH);
    break;
    etc.
```

I would very much appreciate if someone can suggest a more elegant way. Thanks!

Remark: The comment in the code is out-dated. Agent::policy is a reference, of course, not a pointer.

----------------------- AN EDIT (based on the feedback) ----------------------------------

Based on the feedback that I got (thanks!), I have modified the code. The class definitions are:

```
class Policy {
public:
    virtual DigraphNode getBestMove(DigraphNode &node) const = 0;
};

class Agent {
public:
    Agent() {policy = nullptr;}
    void setPolicy(Policy *p) {policy = p;}
    Policy &getPolicy() {return *policy;}
private:
    Policy *policy; // pointer so polimorphism should work
};
```

The usage is:

```
vector<Policy *> agentPolicies; // need this only to free memory!
while (node->getDepth()) {
   int a = node->getDepth() - 1;
   Policy *myPolicy;
   switch(agentTypes[a]) {
   case NON_COMPLIANT:
     myPolicy = new HeuristicBasedPolicy<MultiHeuristic>(nearExitH);
     break;
   ...
   }
   agents[a].setPolicy(myPolicy);
   agentPolicies.push_back(myPolicy);
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < agentPolicies.size(); i++)
   delete(agentPolicies[i]);
```

Please let me know if this was the intention of the people who commented and replied.

Also, the array in the first line of the client code is needed only to keep pointers to later release them. Is this a normal state of affairs to have an array just for the bookkeeping of memory management? Thanks!

Comment: "To avoid using pointers, I made this member a reference". Avoiding pointers is not a goal, it's a means to achieve a goal. What goal are you trying to achieve? "This works". Really? What happens when you call `setPolicy`?

Comment: Pointers need to be allocated and destroyed and someone needs to own them. I wanted to avoid the pain of thinking about these issues. Also, I do not want to increase compilation time by using shared pointers. Sorry, by "works" I meant "passes compilation". I have not had a chance to run the code, since I am still fighting with the compiler about other issues.

Comment: I would say `setPolicy` modifies `noPolicy`.

Comment: Sorry, Jarod42, I did not understand your comment.

Comment: References are set only once (at initialization) and cannot be *rebind* to an other variable.

Comment: Do you mean that the compiler should yell at me for my Agent::setPolicy() code and that I really should go back to using pointers?

Comment: "_I do not want to increase compilation time by using shared pointers_" That sounds pretty uninformed. Which shared pointer implementation did you try? What was the effect on compilation times?

Comment: The compiler will only yell if `Policy`, i.e. the base class, has no copy assignment operator. If it hase one (which would be unwise for a polymorphic base class), it should compile this happily and do some *slicing* (you might want to look that term up) for you: The `policy` reference remains bound to the `noPolicy` static member, but the `Policy` base class part of `noPolicy` gets assigned with the `Policy` base class part of the `HeuristicBasedPolicy` object you assign to it. The rest of the `HeuristicBasedPolicy` is ignored in the assignment and will be discarded.

Comment: @user3593800 Pointers _don't_ necessarily need to be allocated and deleted.  I can easily imagine a case where all `Policy` have static lifetime, for example.  And even when there is allocation and deletion: it's usually implicit in the application logic: an `Agent` might be allocated when you open a connection, for example, and deleted when the connection is closed.

Comment: @user3593800 And I don't really see any point in shared pointers here.  Objects like `Policy` and `Agent` typically have a lifetime defined by the application logic, which means that shared pointers are inappropriate even when they are dynamically allocated.  (Shared pointers are useful in a few special cases, but not generally.  They're really more of an advanced technique.)

Comment: "'I do not want to increase compilation time by using shared pointers' That sounds pretty uninformed. Which shared pointer implementation did you try? What was the effect on compilation times?" I personally have never used smart pointers yet. I did read various posts about them (can't cite a particular one now) and recall something of the sorts "as is the case with all templates, auto_ptr increase compilation times" being said. I am talking about the implementation of Boost that was adopted for the -std=c++11.

Comment: "Pointers need to be allocated and destroyed and someone needs to own them." You are **totally** mistaken and you need to fix it ASAP before making even bigger mistakes. *Objects* need to be allocated and destroyed and someone needs to own them. Pointers are things that *refer to* objects. So are references. They work a bit differently but the differences are not that important.

Comment: By "pointers" I meant "objects that are allocated on the heap". Sorry for the imprecise language.

Comment: I have edited my post with a modified code that uses a pointer class member instead (I do need to be able to modify an agent's policy many a time after the original instantiation; thanks to everyone for correcting my mistake!) I still am not 100% happy with the code as is indicated in the edit and will appreciate further comments. Thanks!

Comment: @n.m Even objects don't necessarily need to be dynamically allocated.  It's true that a lot of objects have arbitrary lifetimes, depending on the program logic, and those do have to be dynamically allocated (since that's the only way to have lifetime which depends on program logic, rather than scope).  But it's quite common for something like `Policy` to be immutable, with a single static instance for each derived type.  And objects like `Transaction` can often be local variables, if transactions are all wrapped in a function call.

Comment: @JamesKanze I include static, automatic and dynamic allocation under one "allocation" term. Don't know if it's the official terminology, but William of Occam would approve.

Comment: @n.m. O.K.  Given the context, I assumed dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, the reference has the problem that it must be
set in the constructor.  And then can never be changed.  If this
is what you want, *and* the class shouldn't be assignable
(probably the case in something called `Agent`), then
a reference is a valid solution.  If the class needs to be
assignable, or you might need to change the policy after it is
constructed, then a pointer is the usual solution.

More generally, I've seen coding guidelines which forbid
reference members, because they make it impossible to make the
object assignable.  Personally, I don't agree with them, because
a lot of classes have identity, and shouldn't support copy and
assignment.  But it's probably fairly idiomatic to
systematically use pointers as class members, even when
a reference would work.

Having said that: using a no-op class is also fairly idiomatic
in cases like this.  It's often easier to have a class invariant
`policy != nullptr`, and just do `policy->something()`, rather
than having to check for `nullptr` all over the place.  (You may
still want the pointer, however, because you may want to change
the policy, particularly if it is a `NullPolicy`, after the
object has been constructed.)  If you do this, you can (and
probably should) have functions like `getPolicy` return
a reference, and functions like `setPolicy` take a reference.

Also, classes like `Policy` are probably immutable (especially
if you share instances of them), so you should be using pointers
to const and references to const.

And finally: *why* do you want to avoid using pointers?  Well
written C++, at least object oriented C++, will be full of
pointers.

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` might be a viable solution here.

Comment: I have edited my post with a modified code that uses a pointer class member instead (I do need to be able to modify an agent's policy many a time after the original instantiation; thanks to everyone for correcting my mistake!) I still am not 100% happy with the code as is indicated in the edit and will appreciate further comments. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that objects with reference members cannot be assignable is not the only reason to avoid reference members. The imho much more important reason is that you don't see what's happening in code that uses the reference. It may work on a local value or it may not. This hides the connections between the objects, which is a fertile ground for bugs. Personally, I restrict my reference usage to constant references as function arguments (which is just an optimization of pass by value semantics).

Comment: @Chnossos A solution to what problem?

Comment: @cmaster I don't see it as dark as you do, but I do see what you're getting at.  In practice, about the only times I'll use references is as parameters to functions and as return values when I _want_ to provide access to internal data (e.g. something like std::vector<>::operator[]`).

Comment: @user3593800 There's a major problem with it: you're not consistent with regards to whether `policy` is allowed to be a null pointer or not.  If it is, then you should never dereference it without first checking whether it is a null pointer; in particular, `getPolicy` should either return a pointer (most likely) or throw an exception if the internal pointer is null.